# Changing hp lap boot options/order

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I've just installed ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10. However, when I restarted the computer after the installation was completed, the computer could not boot. I went to BIOS, and found there a tab "boot options". There I can see a list of options containing:

- OS boot manager
- Hard drive partition:2
- Notebook Ethetnet IPV4
- Notebook Ethermet IPV6
- Card (UEFI)
- Boot From EFI File
- Ubuntu

When I chose the "Ubuntu" option, everything worked fine, as I wanted, I was able to chose whether I want to run windows or ubuntu. 
I dont want to go to bios and choose the boot option every time I turn on my computer. Is there some way to set that "Ubuntu" option as default?

I will be grateful for your respond.

Answer (score 0):

The boot-repair tool (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) solved my problem